# Jquery ajax .html doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
success: function(json) {
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var response = json[i];
         $('#rv-container').html('<p>' + response.name + '</p>' + '<span>' + response.id + '</span>');
    }
        $('#history_tracking').hide();
    
        }
```

In the success callback `$(#rv-container).html()` will not work, but `.prepend` does.

Why doesn't jQuery allow for `.html` in the success callback?
The problem is the html loaded via ajax keeps on piling up ontop of the data already loaded. So it doesn't replace the data currently in the `#rv-container`

#### HTML:

```html
<div id="bottom-toolbar">
  <div id="rv-facet">
    <div id="rv-fix">
      <li id="rv-title">
        Recently Viewed <span class="total_viewed"></span>
        <div id="rv-total" style="float:right; margin-right:25px;"></div>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div id="rv-content">
      <div id="rv-container">
        <div id="history_tracking"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to have prepend replace the contents of the div?

Comment: can you show us your markup??

Comment: If the length of your json is > 1 only the last field will be visible. Does tha last field have a name and id property?

Comment: Yes all of them have an id and name property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling it in a loop, so obviously it makes a difference whether you are resetting the HTML content over and over (`.html()`) or prepending more and more to it (`.prepend()`)?

Comment: @RPM `$('#rv-container').prepend($('<p>' + response.name + '</p>' + '<span>' + response.id + '</span>'))`

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of your loop is defining the element's inner HTML.. So per step in the loop, this would basically be like `var text = "this is a test"`, so that variable would never grow.
You need to append or prepend the data.

```
success: function(json) {
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var response = json[i];
         $('#rv-container').append('<p>' + response.name + '</p>' + '<span>' + response.id + '</span>');
    }
        $('#history_tracking').hide();

        }
```